# After the airlock blew, how much food does Mark have left?

Tags: the-martian

After the airlock blew, how much food does Mark have left?

Comment: Don't add random nonsense to your question just to fill the character limit. Instead make use of that limit to write actual meaningful information.

Comment: Isn't the scene immediately after that people having a meeting discussing how long his food will last?

Answer (score 2):

From the novel, Sol 122:

> The rations will last me to Sol 400... I had 400 plants, probably averaging 5 potatoes each: 2000 taters.